# error: a function-definition is not allowed here before ‘{’ token

Tags: c++

I've been trying to solve the error. How do I solve it? I've tried putting the functions outside the main function but its still not working.

```
int mutexlock = 1, full = 0, emp = 20, x = 0, buffer[100];

void producer();
void consumer();
int randomgenerator();

int main() {

  void producer() {
    int d = randomgenerator();
    buffer[x] = d;
    cout << "\n" << d;
    x++;
  }
  void consumer() {
    x--;
    cout << "\n" << buffer[x] << endl
    cout << "sum" << buffer[x] << (buffer[x] + buffer[x]);
  }
  int randomgenerator() {
    int num = rand() % 6 + 1;
    return (num);
  }
}
```

Error:

```
 error: a function-definition is not allowed here before ‘{’ token
 {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put all functions out of the main function. Besides, please put the code you want to run after program starts in the main function.

Example:

```cpp
int main() {
    producer();
    consumer();
}
```